# Retrieve a list containing NULLS with Linq

Tags: linq, list, null, left-join, nullable

Is it possible to use LINQ to retrieve a list that may contain nulls.

For example if I have a left outer join like so:

```
var query=  from c in db.Customers
                join o in db.Orders
                   on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into sr
                from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select x.OrderId;
```

How do I get to a List that could look like {12,13,null,14,null,11,16,17}?

This doesn't work for me:

```
query.ToList<decimal?>();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You don't explain what you want those `null`s to correspond to. Customers with no orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lc is correct, but it's a bit cleaner to simply cast your select to a nullable type outright.

```
var query=  from c in db.Customers
                join o in db.Orders
                   on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into sr
                from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select (decimal?)x.OrderId;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `x.OrderId` will throw a `NullReferenceException` when `x` is null. You need to check for null *first*, then return the property if there is an object. For example

```
select x == null ? (decimal?)null : x.OrderId;
```

`OrderId` doesn't quite sound like it ought to be a decimal though...

Comment: Thank-you! This has stumped me for a while. Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var query
    = from c in db.Customers
        join o in db.Orders
        on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into sr
        select (sr != null : sr.OrderId : null);
```

Comment: The select should be select (sr != null ? sr.OrderId : null);